# AngularJS: Move to next view and pass along object

Tags: angularjs

I make a query to Parse.com to receive a lot of objects and then display all the objects in a view.

I now want to be able to click on one of the objects, which should load a new page where I can edit them.

My questions is, how do I pass one of the objects from the main view to a detail view where I can edit it?

**When I tried:**

1. With route, **passing the whole object**, but this seems like bad practice, and the whole object is printed out in the status bar:

   ```
   // Route
   .when('/job/:object', {

   <a href="#/job/{{job}}" style=" ">
   ```
2. By just **passing the objectId**, and when query the database to get the object by it's id once the detail view is loaded.

   ```
   .when('/job/:objectId', {

   <a href="#/job/{{job.id}}" style=" ">

   // Get Object by its ID from Parse.com.
   ```
3. Save the whole array of objects in the **$rootScope** in order to access them from the new detail controller.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as SSH said you need to create one angular service which can hold the object , and then when you move from one view to another simply inject the service and access the object.

Here is how you should do this.

```
.service('holdobj',function(){

    var myobj;

    this.set= function(obj){
     myobj = obj;
    };

    this.get= function(){
     return myobj;
    };

});
```

now in your controller

```
.controller(function(holdobj){

    $scope.setObject = function(obj){
      holdobj.set(obj);
    }

});
```

And then when you want to get object simply call `holdobj.get();`

Answer (score 1):

You should save an incoming object in a service, and then use that service across different controllers

Comment: Thanks for reply. How do I save the object to the service when I click one of the <a> ?

Comment: There is a good tutorial at egghead: https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-sharing-data-between-controllers

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are using a shared controller between views I think you could probably set a model before you change the view.

I don't know if there is a way to pass model between controllers when checking router otherwise, without going the old-fashioned way and passing an id to the object, where the second controller would look it up based on that.